# Update Panel + window.open + https

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'am developing with c# and asp.net.

I have some pages with update panels. In this update panels there is a button that redirects to a new window. This is done by calling the window.open with the scriptmanager in code behind. Everything works fine until I don't use https. If I use tunnelling with a router to have a secure line till the router and then use a proxy to access my webpages, the window.open called from the buttons that are in an update panel open a new register card, but there I get the error : page not found. In the url I can see that the router did not put the proxy+IP before the path. That does not happen if I remove the update panel.With Firebug I could see that with the update panel I get a POST and in the resonse the contentType is text/plain. Without the update panel there is a GET and the response contentType is text/html. So what can I do to run this without removing the update panels?

This works fine until I don't use https over my proxy:

```
protected void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     url = "~/Gui/Report/ReportViewer.aspx?ReportName=CustomerReport";
     Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;

     if (page == null) {
         Redirect(url);
     }

     url = page.ResolveUrl(url);

     string script = @"window.open(""{0}"");";

     script = String.Format(script, url);
     ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page,
         typeof(Page),
         "Redirect",
         script,
         true);
}

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
         <dx:ASPxButton runat="server" ID="btnPrint"
               Text="print" OnClick="btnPrint_Click">
         </dx:ASPxButton>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: So do you have a code or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Got it....

the information that the scriptlanguage is javascript is lost if I am using the proxy (strange...?!?!).
If I build the script tags on my own with adding the attribut "language='javascript'" then everything works fine.
Can anybody tell me why this information is lost?

Here the new code:

```
protected void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 url = "~/Gui/Report/ReportViewer.aspx?ReportName=CustomerReport";
 Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;

 url = page.ResolveUrl(url);

 string script = "window.open('" + url + "');";

 System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
 sb.Append("<script language='javascript'>");
 sb.Append(script);
 sb.Append("</script>");

 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page,
     typeof(Page),
     "Redirect",
     script,
     false);
}
```